# Transfer emails from Google Workspace email account to Gmail account without duplicates

Tags: gmail

I have an email account inside Google Workspaces that I will call GW. I also have a Gmail account. The Gmail account is currently forwarding all received emails to the GW account.

The Google Workspaces account is out of storage. However, I have ample storage on Gmail.

I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Move all emails from GW into Gmail

   - Ideally emails which were originally forwarded from Gmail to GW would not be moved so that I don't have duplicate emails
   - Also ideally tags would be preserved
2. Make it so that when I send email from Gmail, it appears that it's coming from GW.

Are these things possible?
(There's other steps above that I'm not getting into because I already know how to do them).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.